# What is source of data for Redshift concurrency scaling for dc2.large node?

Tags: amazon-redshift

My team and I are planning to try to use concurrency scaling, we're experiencing read timeouts during our periodic ETL jobs (we're materializing views every 2h, basically recreating whole tables). We want to try whether concurrency scaling will help us to redirect part of the read queries on concurrent clusters to maintain good read performance.
However, I have a hard time understanding what is the source of data for cluster build from dc2.large nodes.

I understand that dc2.large uses local, per-machine SSD disks to store the data (160GB per node). Which data concurrent cluster will use? Will it copy the data from the main cluster during windup or does it redirect queries somehow? In the case of ra3 nodes, I understand it uses S3 underneath and it will always have recent data, but how it will work for dc2 nodes? I'm concerned that concurrent nodes will use some old data, while we're refreshing data every 2h.

I saw this answer, but I still have a hard time understanding it.
[How does Redshift concurrency scaling work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70025814/how-does-redshift-concurrency-scaling-work)